# The James and Morse filtrations of homotopy groups

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Denote by $JX$ the James construction on a path connected, well-pointed space $X$. This space is filtered by subspaces $X=J_1X\subseteq\dots\subseteq J_nX\subseteq\dots\subseteq JX$ and is the domain of a natural weak equivalence
$$JX\xrightarrow{\sim}\Omega\Sigma X.$$
The following could be set up with somewhat more generality but I will limit the discussion to spheres. Background information is found the references listed below.

> - The **James filtration** of $\pi_*S^n$ is the increasing filtration wherein $F_k(\pi_{r+1}S^n)\subseteq \pi_{r+1}S^n$ is the image of $\pi_r(J_kS^{n-1})$ under the homomorphism
>   $$\pi_r(J_kS^{n-1})\rightarrow \pi_r(JS^{n-1})\xrightarrow\cong\pi_r(\Omega S^n)\cong\pi_{r+1}S^n.$$
> - Let $\Omega' S^n$ be the space of parametrised smooth paths on $S^n$ joining $e_1$ and $e_2$. Write $|\ell|$ to denote the Euclidean length of $\lambda\in\Omega' S^n$, and for $f:S^r\rightarrow\Omega'S^n$ let $|f|=\sup\{|f(z)|\mid z\in S^r\}$. There is an isomorphism $\pi_{r+1}S^n\cong\pi_r\Omega'S^n$, $\alpha\mapsto\alpha^\#$, and we obtain a function $L:\pi_{r+1}S^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ by putting $L(\alpha)=\inf\{|f|\mid f\in\alpha^\#\in\pi_r\Omega'S^n\}$. It is known that $L(\alpha)\in(\mathbb{N}_0+1/2)\pi$ for any $\alpha\in\pi_{r+1}S^n$ and any $r\geq 0$. The **Morse filtration** of $\pi_*S^n$ is the increasing filtration given by
>   $$M_k(\pi_{r+1}S^n)=\{\alpha\in\pi_{r+1}S^n\mid L(\alpha)\leq (k+1/2)\pi\}.$$

Both the James and Morse filtrations are increasing, bounded, and exhaustive. The $F_k(\pi_{r+1}S^n)$'s are subgroups of $\pi_{r+1}S^n$, and, although it might not be obvious, the same is true of the $M_k(\pi_{r+1}S^n)$'s. We have
$$F_0(\pi_rS^n)=M_0(\pi_rS^n)=0$$
and
$$F_1(\pi_rS^n)=M_1(\pi_rS^n)=im\left(\pi_{r-1}S^{n-1}\xrightarrow{\Sigma}\pi_rS^n\right).$$
Furthermore,
$$F_k(\pi_rS^n)=\pi_rS^n,\qquad \text{for}\qquad k(n-1)\leq r<kn$$
holds by cellular approximation, and
$$M_k(\pi_rS^n)=\pi_rS^n\qquad\text{if}\qquad k(n-1)+1\leq r\leq(k+1)(n-1)$$
holds by results of Pitcher. Both filtrations are known to be nontrivial, but the question posed by James some 60 years ago, is if the filtrations are one and the same.

> **Question** Do the James and Morse filtrations agree?

I believe that they do not, but I somewhat lack experience working with the Morse filtration. For example, James has shown that the element of order $p$ in $\pi_{2p}S^3$ has James filtration $p-1$. On the other hand, while nonsuspension elements like the Whitehead products $[\iota_{2n},\iota_{2n}]\in\pi_{4n-1}S^{2n}$ have Morse filtration $2$, I do know how to produce elements in $\pi_*S^n$ of large Morse filtration.

> **Question** What elements in $\pi_*S^n$ have large Morse filtration?

*References*:

1. I. James, *Filtration of the Homotopy Groups of Spheres*, Q. J. Math **9** (1) (1958) 301–309.
2. W. Massey, *Some Problems in Algebraic Topology and the Theory of Fibre Bundles*, Ann. Math. **62** (3) (1955) 327-359.